# Teaching Torah to circumcised non-Jews

Tags: halacha, gentiles, torah-study, brit-milah, chinuch-education

In his supercommentary to Rashi Genesis 7:2, [R. Yissechar Ber Eilenberg](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A8_%D7%91%D7%A8_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%92) cites the following from his teacher [R. Mordecha Yaffe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordecai_Yoffe):

> וטעם שאסור ללמוד תורה לגוי הוא מפני הערלה שבו ויש בו סוד שלא להכניס הטומאה בהיכל הקדש
>
> And the reason it is forbidden to teach Torah to a non-Jew is that he has a foreskin. And there is a secret [mystical idea?] so as not to allow impurity into the holy sanctuary.

- Have any poskim applied this in practice to justify teaching Torah to non-Jews if they are circumcised?
- If yes to the above, given that many non-Jews nowadays are circumcised, can you teach Torah to any non-Jew (if you don't know that they are not circumcised)?

Comment: Nedarim 3:11 [15 ch]